# How can I get the soapenv content in WSO2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

In this case, how can I get the "MyString" content in WSO2 response?

Request:

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
<format>{

          "Name" : "$1",        
          "group": "$3"
       }
</format>
<args>
     <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:Name"/>
     <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:group"/>
</args>
</payloadFactory>                
<call>
       <endpoint key="ep_Server"/>
</call>
```

response:

```
 Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">{"MyString":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJVc2VySWQiOjEsIlN5c3RlbUlkIjoyMSwiUHJvcGVydHlJZCI6OSwiSXNBZG1pbiI6ZmFsc2UsIkNyZWF0ZURhdGVUaW1lIjoiMjAxNy0xMS0wOFQxMDoyMjoxMi45MDA3MjE4KzA4OjAwIn0.k6FyUGwXOAeC63oGsPWz8ttwo1LeDG3vnTbw7dJ18GY"}</text></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Are you sending a json inside an XML? Can you post your request/response separately?

Comment: I have amended as above.Thank you.

Comment: If you call the backend directly, what is the response you get?

Comment: The backend response like this:
{"MyString":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJVc2VySWQiOjEsIlN5c3RlbUlkIjoyMSwiUHJvcGVydHlJZCI6OSwiSXNBZG1pbiI6ZmFsc2UsIkNyZWF0ZURhdGVUaW1lIjoiMjAxNy0xMS0wOFQxMDoyMjoxMi45MDA3MjE4KzA4OjAwIn0.k6FyUGwXOAeC63oGsPWz8ttwo1LeDG3vnTbw7dJ18GY"}

I don't know why the json inside XML.....

Comment: What's the content-type of this?

Comment: The content-type is json

Comment: Please give me the exact Content-Type header value.

Comment: <property name="ContentType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>

Comment: Please enable wire logs and post the logs. http://lakshanigamage.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-enable-wire-logs-in-wso2-esbapim.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
 <log>
     <property name="MyString" expression="json-eval($.MyString)"></property>
 </log>
```

Ref: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/JSON+Support

Comment: I have used this method, it show the error message...

#stringValueOf. Error evaluating JSON Path <$.MyString>. Returning empty result. Error>>> invalid path

Comment: If use below property ,it can get "MyString" in the "text"...
But I just want the "MyString" content....

<property name="MyString" expression="json-eval($.)"></property>

{"text":"{\"MyString\":\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJVc2VySWQiOjEsIlN5c3RlbUlkIjoyMSwiUHJvcGVydHlJZCI6OSwiSXNBZG1pbiI6ZmFsc2UsIkNyZWF0ZURhdGVUaW1lIjoiMjAxNy0xMS0wOFQxMjozMTozMi44MzQxMzIrMDg6MDAifQ.E6iHO73bcbFlp19SnLppsh7NPlU3CXFgwff-VFuSnDE\"}"}

Comment: Try `json-eval($.text.MyString)`

Comment: The same error....
#stringValueOf. Error evaluating JSON Path <$.text.MyString>. Returning empty result. Error>>> java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map

Comment: What do you get for `json-eval($.text)` ?

Comment: like this: 
MyString= {"MyString":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJVc2VySWQiOjEsIlN5c3RlbUlkIjoyMSwiUHJvcGVydHlJZCI6OSwiSXNBZG1pbiI6ZmFsc2UsIkNyZWF0ZURhdGVUaW1lIjoiMjAxNy0xMS0wOFQxMjo1Nzo0My4xMzg2OTg4KzA4OjAwIn0.WTsaCn2CfR70jrDH90SQkqhP5fsr1RKgGNSagXUEPs4"}

Answer (score 0):

In your case the output is not json it's xml containing a text, usually it indicate that you're using text/plain type, I think the issue is there. 
Moreover your output is not matching the sample code you've 
Could you try to put the following before your call:

```
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
```

What is the content type that the service you're calling is returning? Is it valid? If not it could be that wso2 ei is by default considering it's text